# How can I remove alphabet numeric character in notepad file

Tags: excel, ms-word, notepad++, notepad

I am having a text file

```
Example:
793643450715275|Andriod Game Hacker
470734673064253|Andriod Firmရာ
382409221961101|Andriod Solution
709215912481252|AndriodوIOS
248027618719895|Exchange App Andriod Reviews
212241765574268|andrioders
```

I want to remove all alphabet characters

```
Example Like :
793643450715275
470734673064253
382409221961101
709215912481252
248027618719895
212241765574268
```

Anybody tell me how can I do this .I have also try notepad++ but not able to do this

Suggest Me.

Answer (score 4):

In **Notepad++**, please try Find what :

`\D+`

Replace with :

`\r`

in Regular expression Search Mode, Replace All.

In **Word**:

Find what:

`|*^13`

Replace with:

`^p`

check Use wildcards and Replace All.

In **Excel**:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("|",A1)-1)
```

or if number format preferred:

```
 =1*LEFT(A1,FIND("|",A1)-1)
```

and in both cases copy down to suit.

Or Text to Columns with pipe as the delimiter and delete what is not required.

Comment: @N0ddy: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your problem, then you help everyone by tagging it as the accepted answer.